# Why the Email Body is giving different out put?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, html-email

I'm trying to trigger an email from Google App script.

```
const body = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput( "A <b> new task </b> have been added to the Task Manager <br> www.abc.com")
if (props.val == "Jonh"){
MailApp.sendEmail("abc@abc.com",task,body,{name:"ABC"})
}
```

The problem is, email body give nothing but just this
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVl9I.png)

What is the mistake?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) the **body** parameter expects a string. Your `body` probably gets stringified to its type name **HtmlOutput**. I never used it, yet according to [**HtmlOutput**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) something like `MailApp.sendEmail("abc@abc.com",task,body.getContent(),{name:"ABC"})` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, `HtmlOutput` object is directly used as the text body. I think that this is the reason for your issue. And, the 3rd argument of `sendMail` is the text body. In your situation, I thought that HTML body might be your expcted result. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
const body = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("A <b> new task </b> have been added to the Task Manager <br> www.abc.com")
if (props.val == "Jonh") {
  MailApp.sendEmail("abc@abc.com", task, null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: body.getContent() });
}
```

Or, in your script, I think that you can directly use the HTML as follows.

```
if (props.val == "Jonh") {
  MailApp.sendEmail("abc@abc.com", task, null, { name: "ABC",htmlBody: "A <b> new task </b> have been added to the Task Manager <br> www.abc.com" });
}
```

Or,

```
const body = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("A <b> new task </b> have been added to the Task Manager <br> www.abc.com")
if (props.val == "Jonh") {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "abc@abc.com",
    subject: task,
    htmlBody: body.getContent(),
    name: "ABC"
  });
}
```

Or,

```
if (props.val == "Jonh") {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "abc@abc.com",
    subject: task,
    htmlBody: "A <b> new task </b> have been added to the Task Manager <br> www.abc.com",
    name: "ABC"
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [createHtmlOutput(html)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutput(String))
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)
- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))