# Using HTML and HYPERLINKS in Google sheets when sending email with Apps Scripts

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets apps script that sends emails.
Would be lovely if I can somehow include hyperlinks and line breaks with html.
I know htmlBody should somehow do this, but since I'm not that good with coding I've spent days to unsuccessfully figure this out.
Some help would be nice!
I have the following code:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet');
  const data = sh.getRange('B2:E75' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const messages = data.reduce((ar, r) => {
    let overdueValue = r[2];
    if (overdueValue > 19) {
      let url = r[0];
      let da = r[1];
      let pa = r[2];
      let bl = r[3];
      let message = 'https://somelink.com?input=' + url + ' ' + da + ' ' + pa + ' ' + bl + '    ' + 'https://otherlink.com' + url ;
      ar.push(message);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  let subject = "Subject"; 
  MailApp.sendEmail('some@gmail.com', subject, messages.join("\n"));
}
```

edit,

result would be something like that:

```
= '<a href=\"' + url + bl + '">' + bl + '</a>' + ' ' + da + ' ' + pa + ' ' + bl + ' ' + '<a href=\"' + url + da + '">' + da + '</a>' + '<br />';
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected value or your expected situation as an image?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your expected value, I thought that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74177368/7108653 How about this? So, please modify `let message = 'https://somelink.com?input=' + url + ' ' + da + ' ' + pa + ' ' + bl + '    ' + 'https://otherlink.com' + url ;` to `let message = '<a href=\"' + url + bl + '">' + bl + '</a>' + ' ' + da + ' ' + pa + ' ' + bl + ' ' + '<a href=\"' + url + da + '">' + da + '</a>' + '<br />';`.

Comment: And, modify `MailApp.sendEmail('some@gmail.com', subject, messages.join("\n"));` to `MailApp.sendEmail('some@gmail.com', subject, null, {htmlBody: messages.join("")});`, and test it again.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.